# Tool for converting .VYF audio file

Tags: audio, conversion

Is there any tool to convert .VYF audio file to .mp3 or any other audio file?

Comment: Is there a sample of this format somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Samsung PC Studio](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Telephony-SMS-GSM/Samsung-PC-Studio.shtml) software.  I don't have a Samsung phone to check it out, but it seems like it's built to handle all the different file types created by the phone.

An example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Googling unveils two more titles, Eufony and SoftE Audio Converter.
http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/vyf